# Transfer an array of char via pointer to another temp array pointer

Tags: c++, arrays, pointers

I'm learning to use pointer to copy char array.

I have the following code in C++. What I'm trying to do is to transfer and array (set1) using pointer to another pointer array (temp).

But when I try to print out (temp), it is not the same as (set1).

Transfer an array via pointer to another temp array pointer.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    char set1[] = "ABC";

    char* p = &set1[0];

    int tempSize = 0;
    char* temp = new char[256];

    for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
    {
        *temp = *p;
        cout << *temp;   // ABC
        ++temp;
        ++tempSize;

        ++p;
    }

    cout << "\n";

    for (int i = 0; i < tempSize; i++)
    {
        cout << temp[i]; // Why ABC is not printed?
    }

    delete [] temp;

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> // Why ABC is not printed?

Because your pointer is travelling in **undefined behavior** region:

```
char* temp = new char[256];
...
++temp;  // gone !!
```

On top of that,

1. you are not terminating the string with `\0` in the end (may not be needed in your code)
2. `delete[]`ing this corrupt pointer in the end.

Since you are writing for learning purpose, I would suggest simple fix to your code:

```
char* const temp = new char[256];
      ^^^^^ ensures `temp` is not modifiable
```

Now use `temp[i]` for traversing purpose.

Comment: Thanks, I have updated the code to do this.  for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    temp[i] = *p;
    ++p;
}

Answer (score 0):

It's because in the loop copying the array, you change `temp`. After the loop, it points to one beyond the copied data.

Also, you forget to terminate the new allocated array. You should add the character `'\0'` at the end.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is this line:

```
++temp;
```

You are incrementing the pointer and then write to it. In the end `temp[i];` does not point to the beginning of your string, but to the end.

The easiest way to do this is to remove the first `for` loop with:

```
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{
    temp[i] = set1[i];
}
temp[4] = '\0'; // don't forget to close the string
```

Answer (score 0):

C-style strings have a null terminator - "ABC" contains four characters.  Also, I'm not at all sure that the delete call on temp is valid - you have been incrementing it since it was 'newed'.